# How to build two different .tex files from same .tex file

Tags: documentation, workflow

When I prepare an exercise list for my students I use to also include there my own solutions. I prepare these documents with some macros based on `mdframed` and with `comment` help I easily obtain two pdfs, one with exercises and another one with exercises and solutions.

I encourage my students to try to write their solutions with `LaTeX` so I give them the `.pdf` file with exercises and a source `.tex` file without answers. This way, they only have to worry about writing their solutions because the format is already provided. The problem is that I need to have two source files one with problems+solutions and another one only with problems.

What I would like would be to have only one `.tex` file with problems and solutions and, from it be able to extract another `.tex` file without solutions. As a possible frame work suppose a main `.tex` file like:

```
% This is main.tex file
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{exercise} 
This is the first exercise
\begin{solution}
This is my solution
\end{solution}
\end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

from which I want to easily obtain a similar one with empty solutions:

```
% This is student.tex file
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{exercise} 
This is the first exercise
\begin{solution}
\end{solution}
\end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

I suppose I'm looking for something like a `.dtx` file but I've never used it and may be there are better solutions. I'm working on windows so `grep` commands won't work.

Comment: I would write a short parser, which just cut out the text between `\begin{solution}` and `\end{solution}`. But I am not sure whether an analog is possible through LaTeX itself, too.

Comment: Have you considered the [`exam`](http://www-math.mit.edu/~psh/exam/examdoc.pdf) document class?  It won't give you two tex sources, but as @DominikusK. says, you can easily write a parser.

Comment: @JLDiaz: No. I do need two .tex files because I want to give one to the students. I know how to get different pdf from same file.

Comment: @SeanAllred I know exam, exsheets, and some other classes for exercises. With them i can produce different pdfs but i want different source (.tex) files.

Comment: @JLDiaz A luatex solution would be perfect because i want to learn it long time ago.

Comment: @Ignasi Is python installed on site?

Comment: It would be interesting to see if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115379/write-and-read-from-a-latex-temporary-file can be hooked onto arbitrary environments (e.g. `document`,`questions`) while excluding other environments (e.g. `solution`).

Comment: Did you check the `extract` package?

Comment: @Ignasi I added a luatex solution, let me know if you need further customization.

Comment: @ ignasi For a completely different but perhaps equally completely irrelevant solution, see (http://freemathtexts.org/AncillariesManagement/index.php). Described in [http://tug.org/pracjourn/2010-2/schremmer.html].

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Update.

Added support to leave the empty environment in the copy, removing only its contents, or to remove also the `\begin...\end` pair (by default).

---

I programmed a LuaLaTeX solution and tried to make it flexible enough. These are the files which compose the solution:

### `remove-env.lua`

```lua
-- remove-env.lua
omittedEnvironments = {}
omitFileSuffix = "-without"
leaveEmptyEnvs = false

function shouldOmit(line)
  for i,v in ipairs(omittedEnvironments) do
    if (string.find(line, "\\begin{"..v.."}")~=nil) then
       return true
    end
  end
  return false
end

function shouldResume(line)
  for i,v in ipairs(omittedEnvironments) do
    if (string.find(line, "\\end{"..v.."}")~=nil) then
       return true
    end
  end
  return false
end

function dumpfile()
    myout = io.open(tex.jobname..omitFileSuffix..".tex", "w")
    myin = io.open(tex.jobname..".tex", "r")
    omitting = false
    for line in myin:lines() do
      if (not omitting and shouldOmit(line)) then
          if (leaveEmptyEnvs) then myout:write(line.."\n") end
          omitting = true
      end
      if (not omitting) then
         myout:write(line.."\n")
      end
      if (omitting and shouldResume(line)) then
          if (leaveEmptyEnvs) then myout:write(line.."\n") end
          omitting = false
      end
    end
    myout:close()
    myin:close()
end
```

### `remove-env.tex`

```
\directlua{dofile("remove-env.lua")}
\def\omitEnvironment#1{\directlua{table.insert(omittedEnvironments, "#1")}}
\def\omitFileSuffix#1{\directlua{omitFileSuffix="#1"}}
\def\leaveEmptyEnvs{\directlua{leaveEmptyEnvs=true}}
\def\removeEmptyEnvs{\directlua{leaveEmptyEnvs=false}}
\AtEndDocument{\directlua{dumpfile()}}
```

### `MWE.tex`

```
\input remove-env
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{solution}{}{}
\omitEnvironment{solution}
\omitFileSuffix{-sans-sol}

\begin{document}\parindent0pt\parskip1em
  1. \lipsum[1]\hrulefill\par
  \begin{solution}
  2. \lipsum[2]\hrulefill\par
  \end{solution}
  3. \lipsum[3]\hrulefill\par
\end{document}
```

This MWE defines a no-op `solution` environment which acts simply as markup, but of course you can define it in a way that produces some effect in the pdf. Macro `\omitEnvironment` specifies the environment you want to omit. You can use this macro several times to specify several environments, and all of them will be omitted. Macro `\omitFileSuffix` specifies the suffix that will be appended to the output filename.

Run:

```
$ lualatex MWE.tex
```

And you will get two files (and all the usual auxiliar files, of course):

- `MWE.pdf` will be generated as usually, and all the contents (including omitted environments) will be present.
- `MWE-sans-sol.tex` is a copy of `MWE.tex` in which all `solution` environments are removed.

```
$ diff MWE.tex MWE-sans-sol.tex
11,13d10
<   \begin{solution}
<   2. \lipsum[2]\hrulefill\par
<   \end{solution}
```

If you want to remove only the contents of the solution but leave the empty environment, you only have to specify `\leaveEmptyEnvs` at some point of `MWE.tex`. In this case the diff will show:

```
$ diff MWE.tex MWE-sans-sol.tex
12d11
<   2. \lipsum[2]\hrulefill\par
```

---

PS: Thanks to Scott H. who [suggested me](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101543/12571) not to use luatex callbacks, which was my first (and too convoluted) approach

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! It works. Now I have a perfect excuse to learn `LuaLaTeX`.

Comment: My first `lualatex` lesson: changing `\directlua{dofile("remove-env.lua")}` to `\directlua{require("remove-env.lua")}` I can have both `remove-env` files in my `localtex` folder instead of working folder.

Answer (score 15):

A TeX only solution; it assumes that you don't have any other environment whose name starts with the string `soluti` other than `solution`.

Prepare the following `extract.tex` file:

```
\newread\texfileread
\newwrite\texfilewrite
\openin\texfileread=ignasimain.tex % put here the main file name
\immediate\openout\texfilewrite=ignasistudents.tex % put here the secondary file name

\edef\BEGINSOLUTI{\string\begin\string{soluti}
\edef\ENDSOLUTION{\string\end\string{solution}
\newif\ifwritesolution
\writesolutiontrue

\long\def\ignasidecide#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9\relax{%
  \def\temp{#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8}%
  \ignasidecideaux#9}
\long\def\ignasidecideaux#1#2#3#4#5#6\relax{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\temp#1#2#3#4#5}{\BEGINSOLUTI}=0
    \immediate\write\texfilewrite{\ignasiline^^J}
    \writesolutionfalse
  \else
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\temp#1#2#3#4#5}{\ENDSOLUTION}=0
      \writesolutiontrue
    \fi
  \fi
  \ifwritesolution
    \immediate\write\texfilewrite{\ignasiline}
  \fi
}

\endlinechar=-1 \newlinechar=`\^^J
\loop\unless\ifeof\texfileread%
\readline\texfileread to \ignasiline%
\expandafter\ignasidecide\ignasiline%
  \relax\relax\relax\relax%
  \relax\relax\relax\relax%
  \relax\relax\relax\relax%
  \relax\relax%
\repeat%
\csname bye\endcsname%
\csname @@end\endcsname
```

Change the file names as desired. Put this file along with the main file and compile with `pdftex` or `pdflatex` (it's the same).

With your example file, the resulting file will be

```
% This is main.tex file
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{exercise}
This is the first exercise
\begin{solution}

\end{solution}
\end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

Basically we read the main file line by line (ignoring category codes) with `\readline`; if the line starts with

```
\begin{soluti
```

then we write out the line with a blank line following it and set a conditional to false; if the line starts with

```
\end{solution
```

then the conditional is set again to true. The current line is written out if the conditional is true.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem. I ended up using `docstrip`.

The system I set up produces:

- (i) separate tex and pdf files for me (with solutions) and the students (without solutions:),
- (ii) several versions of the exercise, for grouping students, and
- (iii) typesets the only selected topic(s), allowing me to keep all the exercises in the same file.

Here's the outline of the main file containing exercises and solutions:

```
% This is exercises.tex
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{exercise}{}{}
\newenvironment{solution}{}{}

\title{Subject\\\normalsize homework topic:
%<topic1>topic 1
%<topic2>topic 2
}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

%<*topic1>
\begin{exercise}
  Exercise text (topic 1)
%<A>  Version for group A,
%<B>  Version for group B,
%<C>  Version for group C,
%<D>  Version for group D.
  More exercise text.
\end{exercise}
%<*!student>
\begin{solution}
  Solution, visible only in my copy:
%<A> for group A,
%<B> for group B,
%<C> for group C,
%<D> for group D.
\end{solution}
%</!student>

%<*student>
% Template for student's answer.
\begin{solution}

\end{solution}
%</student>

%</topic1>



%<*topic2>
\begin{exercise}
  Exercise text (topic 1)
%<A>  Version for group A,
%<B>  Version for group B,
%<C>  Version for group C,
%<D>  Version for group D.
  More exercise text.
\end{exercise}
%<*!student>
\begin{solution}
  Solution, visible only in my copy:
%<A> for group A,
%<B> for group B,
%<C> for group C,
%<D> for group D.
\end{solution}
%</!student>

%<*student>
% Template for student's answer.
\begin{solution}

\end{solution}
%</student>

%</topic2>

\end{document}
```

And this is the `.ins` file for `topic1`:

```
% This is exercises.ins
\input docstrip
\nopreamble\nopostamble
\askforoverwritefalse
\generate{%
  \file{exercises-topic1-A.tex}{\from{exercises.tex}{student,topic1,A}}%
  \file{exercises-topic1-B.tex}{\from{exercises.tex}{student,topic1,B}}%
  \file{exercises-topic1-C.tex}{\from{exercises.tex}{student,topic1,C}}%
  \file{exercises-topic1-D.tex}{\from{exercises.tex}{student,topic1,D}}%
  \file{exercises-topic1-ME.tex}{\from{exercises.tex}{topic1,A,B,C,D}}%
  %\file{exercises-topic2-A.tex}{\from{exercises.tex}{student,topic2,A}}%
  %\file{exercises-topic2-B.tex}{\from{exercises.tex}{student,topic2,B}}%
  %\file{exercises-topic2-C.tex}{\from{exercises.tex}{student,topic2,C}}%
  %\file{exercises-topic2-D.tex}{\from{exercises.tex}{student,topic2,D}}%
  %\file{exercises-topic2-ME.tex}{\from{exercises.tex}{topic2,A,B,C,D}}%
}
\endbatchfile
```

Finally, a very badly written makefile --- nothing more than a camouflaged bash script, really.  (I guess that ideally, running `make` should produce the `.ins` file automatically ... ahh, some day...)

```
all:
    pdftex exercises.ins
    bash -c 'for I in {A,B,C,D,ME}; do pdflatex exercises-topic1-$$I ; done'
    #bash -c 'for I in {A,B,C,D,ME}; do pdflatex exercises-topic2-$$I ; done'
```

Answer (score 10):

Here's an `awk` program that generates a `TeX` file with everything but the contents of `solution` environments, leaving those environments for students to fill in. A hack for windows follows.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk
# Filter out solution environment
#

BEGIN{
    printing = 1;
}

/begin\{solution/ {
    print 
    print "  write your answer here"
    printing = 0;
}

printing >0 {
    print;
}

/end\{solution/ {
    print 
    printing = 1;
}
```

@HendrikVogt notes that you're on windows. This might work for you: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm

**Edit:** A clumsy windows solution. It uses an online bash shell to save a copy of the `awk` program, save a copy of the `TeX` source, then execute the program on the source.

- Visit http://www.compileonline.com/execute_bash_online.php
- Paste the following code into the shell window, substituting your `TeX` source for
  the example here.
- Execute
- Cut the result from the output window

IMPERFECTION: solution seems to eat white space at the beginning of a line. `TeX` wouldn't care, but users might.

```
cat << 'EOF' > /tmp/myprog 
#!/usr/bin/awk
BEGIN{  printing = 1;}
/begin\{solution/ { print; print "your answer  here"; printing = 0;}
printing >0 { print}
/end\{solution/ { print; printing = 1;}
EOF
#
# paste your TeX document here
cat << 'EOF' > /tmp/mytex 
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Test mathematics:  $e^{i\pi} = -1$.
Test "double" and 'single' quotes and a *.
\begin{exercise}
    Question here: $ 2 + 2 = ?$.
\begin{solution}
    $4$
\end{solution}
\end{exercise}
\end{document}
EOF
awk -f /tmp/myprog /tmp/mytex
```

Output for this test:

[image]

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329323/here-document-that-disables-shell-parsing for the here-document syntax to disable shell interpretation.

Comment: Please note that the OP works on Windows and doesn't look for a solution with `grep` and friends. (On a Unix system I'd use such an external program, too!)

Comment: If I had access to a Windows machine, I would advise that VBS be looked into as an alternative.  Installing open ports is a pain on Windows, and it's much easier to just use the built-in tools (even if far inferior) for single-purpose things like this.

Comment: @HendrikVogt: [`grep` is available for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm). There's also [CygWin](http://www.cygwin.com/) that provides a Unix-like interface and accompanying command-line programming functionality, including `grep`.

Comment: Also $ in the tex could cause trouble. Imagine the document contains the formula $PWD$.

Comment: @JLDiaz  With a here-document quotes work and $$ half works. Any suggestions?

Comment: @EthanBolker Instead of here documents or double quotes, you can use single quotes `'` to delimit the contents. This way `$` is not interpreted by the shell (nor `*`, which also could cause trouble), and double quotes are also allowed. But then single quotes would be problematic (they should be escaped `\'`). I guess there is not a universal solution, but perhaps this is the most safe one.

Comment: @JLDiaz I asked on stackoverflow and got an optimal (not perfect) solution for turning off shell parsing. This answer is now as complete as I can make it. Yours in lua is much more elegant.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks for the heads-up. I didn't know how to disable shell parsing in here documents, and it is a useful knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest option is probably the [extract](http://ctan.org/pkg/extract) package, mentioned by mbork in comments. However, this method will not allow you to nest your solution environment inside the exercise environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  active,
  header=false,
  copydocumentclass=true,
  generate=\jobname-no-solutions,
  extract-env={exercise}
  ]{extract} % http://ctan.org/pkg/extract
\begin{extract*}
% Items executed in both the main and extracted document
% (extract manual, section 5.1)
\newenvironment{exercise}{}{}
\newenvironment{solution}{}{}
\end{extract*}
\begin{document}
\begin{exercise} 
This is the first exercise
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
This is my solution
\end{solution}
\end{document}
```

Resulting in code for the extracted file of:

```
\documentclass{article}
% Items executed in both the main and extracted document
% (extract manual, section 5.1)
\newenvironment{exercise}{}{}
\newenvironment{solution}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
This is the first exercise
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I saw the reference to `extract` package in [Extracting the contents of text in a specified environment into a new file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2575/1952) just after sending my question. So, thank you for providing the example and pointing the problem with nested environments.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using answers package for this purpose.  You can 
prepare different versions of solutions also if you want, a 
marking scheme, a full solution, all from the same file. The documentation
has examples.
Here is how I use it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{answers}%Use this once the solutions are final.
%\usepackage[nosolutionfiles]{answers}%Use this while preparing solutions.%
\Newassociation{sol}{nothing}{ans}
\newcommand{\nothingparams}{\relax}
\begin{document}
\Opensolutionfile{ans}[mysolution-file]
\begin{Filesave}{ans}
\begin{center}
%details regarding examination etc.
\end{center}
\begin{enumerate}
\end{Filesave}
\begin{exercise}
......
\end{exercise}
\begin{sol}
.......
\end{sol}
....


\begin{Filesave}{ans}
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{Filesave}
    \Closesolutionfile{ans}
\newpage
     %\input{mysolution-file.tex}%Remove the comment after finalising.
    \end{document}
```

Explanation: Everything you include between \begin{sol} and \end{sol} is written to 
the file mysolution-file.tex.  If you choose the no solutionfiles option, the solution
is printed right below the question. This is convenient while preparing questions. After
finalising you can disable this line and enable the line without the option. You can also enable the \input command in the end. All the solutions are printed after the question paper. Everything between \begin{Filesave}{ans} and \end{Filesave} is saved to the file mysolution-file.tex. I use this to write information regarding the examination to the solution file. I also use them to enclose the solution in enumerate environment. Alternatively, you can write another main tex file and \include the mysolution-file.tex.

**Edit** I read the question again.  You need a texfile with the solutions removed also.  You can use extract package to produce a solution file with the portions enclosed between \begin{sol} and \end{sol} removed.