# Removing solutions in LaTeX source

Tags: exam

Let's imagine I'm teaching a class, and I want to use the `exam` package to write up a homework assignment.  I'm aware that I could compile two different PDF documents -- one containing solutions, using `\documentclass[answers]{exam}`, and one without solutions, using `\documentclass{exam}`.  (Alternatively, I could make versions with and without the `\printanswers` directive.)

However, if the students will typeset their own solutions using LaTeX, the ideal approach would be to create two different *source* versions of the LaTeX file -- one with solutions and one without.  Then, I could distribute the no-solution version of the `.tex` file (perhaps in addition to the no-solution version of the `.pdf` file), and students wouldn't have to worry about manually re-typing the problem statements.

With that in mind, is there any easy-to-automate way to create a copy of a given LaTeX source file with solutions removed?

Comment: Welcome! Which operating do you use and which tex distribution?

Comment: Related, or possibly duplicate, and with several answers given: [How to build two different .tex files from same .tex file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101479)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I have come up with; I'm curious whether there are any simpler or more robust options.

My solution is UNIX-specific and uses a tool called [`gpp`](http://en.nothingisreal.com/wiki/GPP), although it might be possible to substitute other [general-purpose macro processors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_macro_processor) like `m4`.

The file `input.tex` looks like the following:

```
\documentclass[answers,12pt]{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question Here is a question
\begin{solution}\hideSolution{
Here is a lengthy solution.

It may contain many paragraphs.
}\end{solution}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Then, the relevant commands are:

```
# To generate the with-solutions .tex file:
gpp input.tex -T -o solutions.tex -D'hideSolution(a)=\a'

# To generate the no-solutions .tex file:
gpp input.tex -T -o problems.tex -D'hideSolution(a)='
```

The `-T` option tells `gpp` to use LaTeX-style macros (as opposed to C-style macros).

The main downside to this approach is that you have to remember to add a special command, `\hideSolution{...}` -- otherwise the solution won't actually be removed.  (Because of this, it's a good idea to actually run `pdflatex` on the no-solution `.tex` file and preview the results before distributing to students.)  Another downside is that `input.tex` can't be processed by LaTeX without first running it through `gpp`.

As vonbrand mentioned, a better approach might be to write a Perl or Python script to pre-process particular environments (like `\begin{solution}...\end{solution}`) such that their contents are removed from the 'no-solution' version.  But that takes a fair amount of error-prone custom coding, and it'd be great to reuse someone else's solution if one exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can e.g. write questions and answers into environments (that you suitably define), and use an external script in e.g. Perl or Python to strip out the answers to give just questions in LaTeX to your students.

Or just use a package like `answers` to ship out the answers to new files, and typeset the questions and answers separately. Hand your students just the PDF with the questions.

Answer (score 0):

For homework (just a few questions) this is overkill. I just make up a homework handout, with `enumerate` to number the questions. Each item gets a comment labelling its position, like `% 20151h4` for year/term/homework/question (and even `a` and so on if there are subquestions). The answers I write up in another file, labelled the same way (so they are easy to match up to collect questions and solutions later). Thus I can hand the students the typeset questions and the corresponding full source (for reference, if they need to reproduce notation or so). The full solutions can be published later, and handed to the TAs for grading. Asking students to repeat the questions in their hand ins is pointless, in my opinion.