# Babel, active chars, ifthenelse and tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel

This question is a build-up on the "classical" [Problem with babel and tikz using \draw](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166772/problem-with-babel-and-tikz-using-draw); it is known that the `babel` package, in some language, make `><'` actives and wreak havoc with `tikzpicture` environment.

The new (3.0+) `tikz` has a solution as a package named `babel`; it works a treat almost everytime --- unless you use it in this MNWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usetikzlibrary{babel} % this works most of the time, but not in
                       % an \ifthenelse 
\newboolean{solution} \setboolean{solution}{true} 

\begin{document}

\ifthenelse{\boolean{solution}}{

    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
        \draw [thin, ->] (-1,0)  -- (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}

 }% end \ifthenelse{\boolean{solution}}{
{
% not solution here 
}

\end{document}
```

which will fail with the infamous

```
Paragraph ended before \language@active@arg> was complete.
```

Now, the classical solution of avoid active characters in `babel` will work (and it is arguably the right one, thanks to unicode and utf-8 ubiquity), so just using

```
 \usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
```

will solve the thing. Anyway, is this an expected behavior? Is it possible fix `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` to work around this problem? And if not, is there a macro to obtain the same effect of the `es-noquoting` option *after* the fact, so I can correct a previous call of `babel` in a random class/package?

Comment: You can put `\deactivatequoting` anywhere in you preamble or document, to turn off the special meaning of `<` and `>`.

Comment: Not related with your question but, may be, with your code: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/266117/1952, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101479/how-to-build-two-different-tex-files-from-same-tex-file

Comment: Tikz library `babel` only sets a couple of tikz which instruct tikz to deal appropiately with special chars in the context of tikz nodes and paths, but probably `ifthen` package contains some kind of `scantokens` which reads the argument when the special chars are still active, so tikz has no chance to apply its wizardry

Comment: A (stupíd) workaround is to just switch languages for the offending stretch (here the whole tikzpicture).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly what is happening but `ifthen` is interfering here. If I replace with a simple if-macro it works without any problems

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{babel} % this works most of the time, but not in
                       % an \ifthenelse 
\newif\ifboolsolution
\boolsolutiontrue

\begin{document}

\ifboolsolution%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
        \draw [thin, ->] (-1,0)  -- (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\else%
%
\fi%
\end{document}
```

with the package list

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
   babel.sty    2016/02/24 3.9q The Babel package
 spanish.ldf
    tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
     pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
  pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2016/01/03 v1.0q Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
```

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that when the `tikzpicture` is in the argument to another command, the category codes are frozen and the trick used by the `babel` library no more works.

The (admittedly not so nice) workaround is to disable the `quoting` feature of `babel-spanish`, that is not so important now that `csquotes` can do the same service in a cleaner way.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usetikzlibrary{babel} % this works most of the time, but not in
                       % an \ifthenelse 
\newboolean{solution} \setboolean{solution}{true} 

\begin{document}

\ifthenelse{\boolean{solution}}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
        \draw [thin, ->] (-1,0)  -- (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
 }% end \ifthenelse{\boolean{solution}}{
{%
% not solution here 
}

\end{document}
```

This problem is not limited to `\ifthenelse`; if I define

```
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{#1}
```

and call

```
\foo{\begin{tikzpicture}\draw [thin, ->] (-1,0)  -- (0,0);\end{tikzpicture}}
```

the error is the same.

---

The problem seems to be specific to `babel-spanish`. If I try the same code with `babel-czech`, which makes `-` into a shorthand, the code works.

Comment: Does it help to use `\shorthandoff`  ?

Comment: @percusse I guess it helps, but placed *before* `\ifthenelse`

Comment: @percusse I think the problem is specific with `babel-spanish`, because it uses a slightly different mechanism for shorthands than standard `babel`.

Comment: @percusse For instance, `czech` makes `-` into a shorthand, but the code works.

Comment: Indeed I tried to follow the catcodes but couldn't keep up with it.

Comment: The problem appears to occur also with `french`, notably with `!`. Any idea other than inserting shorthandoff everywhere?

Comment: @TomHirschowitz Sorry, no; for `>` in Spanish one can disable the “quoting” feature. With French one cannot disable `!` and the other special punctuations. It shouldn't happen with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.