# ifthen + [ngerman]babel + pgfplots + axis + text height = ☇

Tags: pgfplots, babel, german, ifthenelse, shorthands

Continuing [[ngerman]babel + pgfplots + axis + text height = ☇](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/547146/ngermanbabel-pgfplots-axis-text-height) and feeding

```
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{techrep}
\setboolean{techrep}{true}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\begin{document}
\section{Section name}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{techrep}}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}\shorthandoff{"}
    \begin{axis}[
      xmax         = 5.5,
      xmin         = 0,
      ymax         = 5.5,
      ymin         = 0,
      extra x tick style = {text height=height("0")},
      extra x ticks = 3
      ]
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}{}
\end{document}
```

(in a real example, there would be a lot of unrelated code around, which is all abstracted away here) to `pdflatex`, we obtain

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.22 }{}

? X
```

Who is the culprit and what to do? Using the TikZ library `babel` doesn't help, neither does inserting `\shorthandoff(")` at various places (though, I've not tested ALL places).

Comment: I think [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/314884/194703) is very related. `\begingroup\shorthandoff{"}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{techrep}}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xmax         = 5.5,
      xmin         = 0,
      ymax         = 5.5,
      ymin         = 0,
      extra x tick style = {text height=height("0")},
      extra x ticks = 3
      ]
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}{}\endgroup` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/314884/194703) is related. As far as I can see, the answers there provide only workarounds. Here is another workaround.

```
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\documentclass{article}
\newboolean{techrep}
\setboolean{techrep}{true}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\begin{document}
\section{Section name}
\begingroup\shorthandoff{"}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{techrep}}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xmax         = 5.5,
      xmin         = 0,
      ymax         = 5.5,
      ymin         = 0,
      extra x tick style = {text height=height("0")},
      extra x ticks = 3
      ]
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}{}\endgroup
\end{document}
```

I think that not using the `ifthen` package could be the best solution. If you load `pgf`, you can always introduce test integers and work with `\ifnum` or `\ifcase`, or a `\newif`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newif\iftechrep
\techreptrue
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\begin{document}
\section{Section name}
\iftechrep
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xmax         = 5.5,
      xmin         = 0,
      ymax         = 5.5,
      ymin         = 0,
      extra x tick style = {text height=height("0")},
      extra x ticks = 3
      ]
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\else  
\fi
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Just_A_Man But you could just use an `\ifnum` instead, can't you?

Comment: @Just_A_Man Internally the Boolean is just like a `\newif`. I added an example using such a built in Boolean. This has the great advantage that you can link it to the `/.is if` key handler from pgf.

Answer (score 1):

You might locally define active `"` to do what's expected by Ti*k*Z:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\newboolean{techrep}
\setboolean{techrep}{true}

\begin{document}
\section{Section name}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{techrep}}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}\edef"{\string"}
    \begin{axis}[
      xmax         = 5.5,
      xmin         = 0,
      ymax         = 5.5,
      ymin         = 0,
      extra x tick style = {text height=height("0")},
      extra x ticks = 3
      ]
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}{}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xmax         = 5.5,
      xmin         = 0,
      ymax         = 5.5,
      ymin         = 0,
      extra x tick style = {text height=height("0")},
      extra x ticks = 3
      ]
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

I have set twice the picture for comparison.

[image]

However, you can exploit the fact that `\newboolean{techrep}` is essentially the same as `\newif\iftechrep`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\newboolean{techrep}
\setboolean{techrep}{true}

\begin{document}
\section{Section name}
\iftechrep
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xmax         = 5.5,
      xmin         = 0,
      ymax         = 5.5,
      ymin         = 0,
      extra x tick style = {text height=height("0")},
      extra x ticks = 3
      ]
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\fi
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Just_A_Man `\unless\iftechrep`?