# Errors with tikzcd when labeling arrows

Tags: tikz-cd

I am trying to create some diagrams using tikz-cd, but I get several errors the moment I add any label to the arrows. To be precise, this works fine:

```
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
G \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & G \cdot x \arrow[d] \\
G \arrow[r]                   & G \cdot x
\end{tikzcd}
\]
```

While this gives errors:

```
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
G \arrow[r, "a"] \arrow[d] & G \cdot x \arrow[d] \\
G \arrow[r]                   & G \cdot x
\end{tikzcd}
\]
```

The errors I get are the following

```
Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 621. [\include{chapter1}]
Improper \prevdepth. [\include{chapter1}]
Missing \endcsname inserted. [\include{chapter1}]
You can't use `\relax' after \the. [\include{chapter1}]
Improper \prevdepth. [\clearemptydoublepage]
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. [\clearemptydoublepage]
```

I am using the babel package with the spanish language, which has given me problems with tikzcd before, but that does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: Please prepare a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the error message you get and that supposts the claim "babel package with the spanish language [...] that does not seem to be the problem."

Comment: If I try to compile your code using `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
G \arrow[r, "a"] \arrow[d] & G \cdot x \arrow[d] \\
G \arrow[r]                   & G \cdot x
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}` I get the same error message as you. Commenting out the `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` line results in no error messages.

Comment: To make your code compilable using the spanish babel option, add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` as in `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
G \arrow[r, "a"] \arrow[d] & G \cdot x \arrow[d] \\
G \arrow[r]                   & G \cdot x
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}`.

Comment: Commenting out the babel package didn't seem to work, that is why I said that the error was not related. However, the \usetikzlibrary{babel} has solved the problem, thank you very much :)

Comment: @leandriis most of the time people *thinks* that error is not babel-related because even if you comment the babel line, you have to remove the `.aux` file to eliminate the error. Using the `babel` Ti*k*Z library works most of the times, but in this age of UTF8 my options is using `shorthands=off` in the babel invocation and be happy... more or less.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314884/babel-active-chars-ifthenelse-and-tikz

Comment: To the OP: take into account these two issues, that I think are still not fixed: https://github.com/jbezos/babel-spanish/issues/7 and https://github.com/jbezos/babel-spanish/issues/6, so the best way to use babel en Spanish is `\usepackage[english, spanish, es-noshorthands, shorthands=off]{babel}`  (@leandriis if you are interested... ;-) )

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solve with the comments.