# Correcting Linux Commands

Tags: command-line

I need to correct some Linux commands in Latex, I'm currently using the *minted* library because for me is the better looking one but I can't manage to make too long command break into two parts.

For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english, openany, oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

% Paquetes utilizados en el documento 
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage{minted}  

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
 
\noindent
Instalar todas las dependencias necesarias de Home Assistance Superviced 
\begin{minted}{bash}
   $ apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get install jq wget curl avahi-daemon udisks2 libglib2.0-bin network-manager dbus apparmor -y 
\end{minted} 
 
\end{document}
```

This code shows the command like this:

[image]

Is there someway to make it all fit by breaking it into more lines? I appreciate the help.

Comment: you can just linebreak the input

Comment: Replace `\begin{minted}{bash}` with `\begin{minted}[breaklines]{bash}`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  I tried that but it doesn't work, if what you mean is putting a \\ when I want the line to break.

Comment: no not \\ , just a newline minted is like verbatim, it obeys the lines in the source

Comment: I don't know how to force Latex to do it, but bash allows a newline after any of `&&`, `||`, `&`, `|`

Answer (score 1):

As David said, you can just do it:

```
\begin{minted}{bash}
   $ apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && 
     apt-get install jq wget curl avahi-daemon udisks2 \
        libglib2.0-bin network-manager dbus apparmor -y 
\end{minted}
```

...which will give the following image. I do not know if automatic line breaking is possible, or desirable (you can break lines semantically by hand).

[image: nice indented code]

PD: `utf-8` has been the default for a while, so the `inputenc` package is not needed; but you probably [*will* want `T1` font encoding](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc); moreover, if you use Unicode input for Spanish, I heartily suggest to use:

```
\usepackage[spanish, es-noshorthands, shorthands=off]{babel}
```

to avoid [future problems with active chars](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314884/babel-active-chars-ifthenelse-and-tikz) (not needed for Spanish if you use Unicode!).