# How to extract only the body of a tex file, removing the preamble?

Tags: extract, body, document

I want to extract only the body of a tex file (say, `mwe.tex`), and reuse that body as a child file of another tex file by `\input`. To do so, I have to remove the preamble and `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

I tried to extract the contents of text in `\begin{document}`...`\end{document}` and produce a child tex file (say `mwe-child.tex`), using `extract` package following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2571/169454). However, `mwe-child.tex` does not contain any portion of `mew.tex`.

What am I missing when I use `extract` package? Or is there another way to programmatically extract the contents of the body (inside between `\begin{document}`...`\end{document}`) in general?

## mwe.tex

```
\documentclass[
]{article}

\usepackage[active, generate=test-extract, extract-env={document}, copydocumentclass=false, handles=false]{extract}

\begin{document}

This is a body that I want to extract.

\end{document}
```

## mwe-child.tex

```
%% 
%% This is file, `test-extract.tex',
%% generated with the extract package.
%% 
%% Generated on :  2022/12/01,2:19
%% From source  :  test2.tex
%% Using options:  active,generate=test-extract,extract-env={document},copydocumentclass=false,handles=false
%%
```

Comment: This can be done using the [subfiles package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/subfiles/subfiles.pdf), that allows for importing a file and skipping the preamble and \begin{document} and \end{document}.

Comment: @Marijn Thank you for your valuable comment! Why don't you post your suggestion as an answer post? I'll upvote it!

Comment: why use a complicated system? I would simply put  the body of the document in main.tex and have  each of your documents `\input` that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have standalone tex files (that have a preamble) for short reports and I want to input the contents of these tex files into another main tex file to make a large report. It is not feasible to copy and paste the contents of the short reports to create child files, since I have numerous short reports...

Comment: @Carlos let's close as a duplicate instead.

Comment: Actually [this answer from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67769927/10215301) helped me: `\usepackage{docmute}` is the solution which I needed.